# Bootstrap CSS to child divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie, I have following structure

```
<div class="row bottom">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="images/logo-main-bottom.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I add/apply a CSS on all 'row' divs that comes under 'row bottom'?

Answer (score 3):

a css rule for that would look like

```
.row.bottom .row{
    //style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take any one class row or bottom

```
.row{
    //add required css 
}
```